# No asyncio.timeout provided in python3.5?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.5

According to the `python3.5` documentation there should be a Handle
called `timeout` in the `asyncio` module [->documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.timeout).

But if I try to use it  `python3.5` tells me, that there is no `asyncio.timeout`:

```
$ python3.5
Python 3.5.0+ (default, Oct 11 2015, 09:05:38) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux
>>> import asyncio
>>> asyncio.timeout(3)
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'timeout'
```

I have already searched the web, but I was unable to find any solution.

I am using `Linux <my hostname> 4.2.0-27-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 04:49:08 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

So how can I use `asyncio.timeout`, why isn't it where it should be, or how can I bypass my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will appear in Python 3.5.2

For now you can use `Timeout` class from `aiohttp` with the same behavior.

Comment: hmm funny, as it is listed under `python3.5.1`.

Comment: the same with the keyword `await`? it seems to be missing, too.

Comment: it just tells me `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task`. Do I have to create a `asyncio.Task` to use it?

Comment: `aiohttp.Timeout` as well as `asyncio.timeout` should be used inside coroutine only (a function with `yield from` or `await` inside).

Comment: I am using it this way: `with aiohttp.Timeout(self.timeout) as t:res += await self._read()`.

Comment: btw if I use only `res += await self._read()` I get a SyntaxError.

Comment: I assume you have Python 3.5. If it's true you can get SyntaxError only if you use `await` statement outside of coroutine (`async def`). The same as `SyntaxError` if `yield` statement is used on module level.

Comment: ah ok thank you. btw there is nothing about this behaviour in the docs... :-\

Comment: Honestly I don't remember where doc says that `yield` is forbidden in module context -- but we are living with that for more than decade :)

Comment: It seems that `asyncio.timeout` was cancelled — see [Async-sig asyncio.timeout() is not portable](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/async-sig/2016-June/000033.html) and [Resurrect asyncio.timeout() context manager · Issue #392 · python/asyncio](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/392)